# pygrametl Dimension abstraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygrametl

Can someone with experience with pygrametl package in python help me understand below error

Sample code from pygrametl documentation :

```
productDimension = Dimension(
    name='product',
    key='productid',
    attributes=['name', 'category', 'price'],
    lookupatts=['name'])
```

Code that I have written :

```
artist_dim=Dimension(
    name='Artist_dim',
    key='row_id',
    attributes=['row_id','Artist_name','Artist_type','Country','ETL_BATCH_ID'],
    lookupatts=['Artist_name']
    )
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "artist_petl.py", line 40, in <module>
        attributes=['row_id','Artist_name','Artist_type','Country','ETL_BATCH_ID']
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygrametl\tables.py", line 189, in __init__
        (self.quote(key), name))
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygrametl\__init__.py", line 663, in execute
        self.__cursor.execute(stmt, arguments)
    TypeError: expecting a dictionary, sequence or keyword args
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but you shouldn’t add the *key* to the *attributes*:

> *attributes*: a sequence of the attribute names in the dimension table. Should not include the name of the primary key which is given in the key argument.

Source: http://chrthomsen.github.io/pygrametl/doc/api/tables.html (see Dimension class arguments)